Prove That the Condition Number of A is Greater Than or Equal to the Condition Number of D in the LDL^T Decomposition
Let $A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix with an $LDL^T$ decomposition:
$$A = L D L^T,$$
where $L$ is a unit lower triangular matrix, $D$ is a diagonal matrix.
I would like to prove that the condition number of $A$, denoted as $\kappa(A)$, is greater than or equal to the condition number of $D$, denoted as $\kappa(D)$:
$$ \kappa(A) \geq \kappa(D). $$
Here, the condition number $\kappa$ can be either the $p$-condition number:
$$ \kappa_p(A) = \| A \|_p \cdot \| A^{-1} \|_p, $$
where $ \| \cdot \|_p$ is the $p$-norm ($p \geq 1$) ,
or the Frobenius condition number:
$$ \kappa_F(A) = \| A \|_F \cdot \| A^{-1} \|_F, $$
where $ \| \cdot \|_F $ is the Frobenius norm.
I am seeking a rigorous proof of this inequality. Any help is appreciated.
There has been a proof in the case of $p=2$ (A question about the positive definite matrices and condition number), but I do not know how to deal with the remaining situations.
